# Winforms apps. ChromiumWebBrowser component is slow displaying the website

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have created a winforms app with CefSharp dll.

I used the ChromiumWebBrowser component.

this is my code:

```
  public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var chromiumWebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
            this.pContainer.Controls.Add(chromiumWebBrowser);
            chromiumWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
```

It is a simple app displaying a form on my website, using the ChromiumWebBrowser component.

When I execute my app on my computer, it displays the form with the webpage quickly (a few seconds).

However, when I execute the app on a remote server, it takes 30 seconds longer to render.

What could be the cause of the slow render time?

Comment: Hello. Any ideas why it takes time?
I have a shared folder with this app.
and it only happens when i run this app from the shared remote folder.

Thanks.

Comment: We probably need more details to help you.  How are you running your app on the remote server? What happens if you just launch Chrome on the server and navigate to `https://www.google.com`, is it slow or fast?  If Chrome is slow then there's probably some sort of network latency due to firewalls or security or whatnot.  But If Chrome is fast while your app is slow, have you tried profiling?  If so, what are the results?

Comment: What version are you using? Check the log file https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: @amaitland 
95.7.14 version.
I don't have errors in my debug.log file.

I have a shared remote folder in my computer.
and it includes all necessary files and when I click on the exe file it starts slowly but works.

If I copy the content of the shared remote folder to my local folder.
and click on the exe file, than it starts fast.

what could be my issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Chromium is not designed to run from network folders/shared folders. I'm not aware workaround, running locally is recommend.